# Why return self in an eval'd class definition?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code example:

```
drop_class = eval "class #{self}::LiquidDropClass < Liquid::Drop; self; end"
```

I understand what it's doing, but I don't understand why `self` is returned within the class definition. Is this even necessary, or is it an artefact of the eval class definition method?

In this case, methods are added later on to the class.

**UPDATE**
My confusion is around this:

```
class XYZ:::LiquidDropClass < Liquid::Drop

end
```

vs

```
eval "class XYZ::LiquidDropClass < Liquid::Drop; self; end"
```

I don't need the self in the first example and the class is created fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of a class (and module) definition body (note that a class definition body is an expression, and thus has a value; in fact, *everything* in Ruby is an expression and thus has a value, there are no statements) is the value of the last expression evaluated inside the class definition body. If `self` *weren't* the last expression inside that particular class definition body, the class definition body would be empty, and thus its value would be `nil`, i.e. `drop_class` would be `nil`.

Before `Object#singleton_class` was added to the core library, the idiomatic way to get a reference to the singleton class was to open the singleton class and have it evaluate to `self`, e.g.:

```
class Object
  def singleton_class; class << self; self end end
end
```

Note that this particular piece of code, doesn't actually require `eval`, it could just as well (and probably clearer) be written as (untested):

```
drop_class = class const_get(to_s)::LiquidDropClass < Liquid::Drop; self end
```

Actually, in both cases the class can also be retrieved via other means, so assigning it to `drop_class` (and thus evaluating `self`) is not strictly necessary.

Comment: The `singleton_class` polyfill needs another `;` but is probably a much better way of doing it than with the `const_get` shennanigans.

Comment: I'm kind of getting it. Are you saying that `def foo; end` also returns self and that's why it's not necessary normally to return self before the end of a class definition?

Comment: @BrendonMuir: It's not quite clear to me what you mean by "`def foo; end` also returns `self`". `def foo; end` is a method definition expression, it doesn't "return" anything. Only method calls return something. However, it *evaluates* to something: a method definition expression evaluates to the name of the method (represented as a `Symbol`) being defined, e.g. `def foo; end` evaluates to `:foo`. Or, if you mean that the *method* returns `self`, that is not true. A method returns the value of the last expression that is evaluated inside the method body (unless there is an explicit `return`).

Comment: In *your* example, the method body is empty, i.e. the last expression evaluated inside the method body is the empty expression, which evaluates to `nil`. So: `def foo; end #=> :foo` and `foo #=> nil`.

Comment: Thanks @JörgWMittag, I know what you mean about the implicit return of a method. I'll update my question to clarify my confusion.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I get your answer now. We want to store the singleton class in a variable so we need to evaluate to self.